# Photoshop—"scratch disk is full" error

Tags: hard-drive, adobe-photoshop

Using a Macbook Air, I have 60Gb free space on my hard drive, yet I can't crop an image (W x H, Resolution setting) because "the scratch disks are full".

What does the error mean? How do I fix it? I can't imagine Photoshop's doing an operation that requires more than 60Gb of spare disk space...

Comment: There are some suggestions here that might help you: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1224354

Comment: @TMHahn The issue the OP is facing is different from the one that is being answered in the thread.

Comment: @TMHahn that thread talks about freeing up space, and defragging the disk. I have been told that Macs don't need to be defragged, because they handle memory storage differently, and it will only wear down the hard drive. I also have 60Gb free, so I don't think I'd need an extra Gb or two by deleting temp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this guide](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/f/scratchdisk.htm) here with a simple Google Search.

If you are getting a "scratch disk full" error when attempting to crop an image, you probably have accidentally entered the size and resolution values in the options bar for the crop tool. You could have also possibly entered the values in the wrong units. This can cause massive render issues as it will try to generate an incredibly large file, ultimately causing the error. The solution to this issue is to press clear in the options bar after selecting the crop tool, but before you drag a crop selection.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that (and many others) before but I didn't read that far—only to where it talked about freeing space, and I thought that wasn't applicable because I had so much space already. The final answer was that  I was trying to make the image 1900x1600cm, not px